# Minecraft Server with Hamachi Connection Issue - java.net.connectexception: Connection Refused

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, hamachi

So I had been running a Minecraft server for a while just fine. I was running it off of a desktop computer. I was using Hamachi to allow people to connect, so they would connect to a network that the desktop was on. Eventually, people stopped really playing on the server, so after months of no activity, I turned it off. This was several months ago.

Recently, someone who had been playing on the server said they were interested in revisiting it. So I go to turn it on on the desktop same as usual. However, when my friend tried to join, it wouldn't allow him to join, and said `java.net.connectexception: Connection Refused`.

No amount of retrying or restarting would fix this. I tried to join the server from my laptop and got the exact same error. So I assume it is an issue on the server end and not with the people trying to join.

However, as I mentioned, I haven't changed anything. It's the same Hamachi network and the same server files.

Hamachi shows that everyone is connected. Green bubbles (direct tunnel) on everyone's end.

So what could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Let me know if there is any other information that might be relevant, and I'll edit it in if I know.

Comment: Have you updated Hamachi on either end? Everyone running the correct version of Hamachi? Have any of you changed your network information (IPs, ISPs, etc) - check if your firewalls still have the same parts allowed for the connection?

Comment: @Ben I'm running Hamachi version 2.1.0.821. I am checking to see if everyone is running the same version right now. I haven't changed any firewall settings that I'm aware of.

Comment: They also need to check their settings as well. Everyone needs to make sure that their connections are correct, so I would suggest focussing on making sure you're all set up before working on their end